# Seek predicate not using all available columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a strange query compilation issue which is hard to reproduce. It only happens under high load and cannot be easily repeated.

- There is a table T with columns A,B,C,D.
- There is a non-unique clustered index on T(A, B, C, D).
- There is a query SELECT * FROM T WHERE A=@P1 AND B=@P2 AND (C=@P3 OR
  C=@P4) AND D=@P5. The seek condition is on all columns of the
  clustered index, the 3-rd column has an OR.

The problem is that the query plan for this query has Seek Predicate only on A and B! The predicate on C and D is an ordinary predicate, so this means that search tree on columns C and D is not utilized.

The data types for all parameters match column data types.

Could anyone provide any hints on why this could be happening? SQL version is 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2789.0 (X64)

Comment: Do you ever actually get a plan for a parameterised query which does perform an equality seek on all 4 columns? If so are you using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`?

Answer (score 8):

For a parameterised query It can't just do two seeks on

```
WHERE A=@P1 AND B=@P2 AND C=@P3 AND D=@P5
```

and

```
WHERE A=@P1 AND B=@P2 AND C=@P4 AND D=@P5
```

Because if `@P3 = @P4` that would incorrectly bring back duplicate rows. So it would need an operator that removed duplicates from these first.

From a quick test this end it appears to be dependant upon the size of the table whether or not you get that. In the test below `245`/`246` rows is the cut off point between plans (this was also the cut off point between the index fitting all on one page and it becoming 2 leaf pages and a root page).

```
CREATE TABLE T(A INT,B INT,C INT,D INT)

INSERT INTO T
SELECT TOP (245) 1,2,3,5
FROM master..spt_values v1

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON T(A, B, C, D)

SELECT index_level,page_count, record_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),object_id('T'),1,NULL, 'DETAILED')

DECLARE @C1 INT = 3,
        @C2 INT = 4

 SELECT * FROM T WHERE A=1 AND B=2 AND (C=@C1 OR C=@C2) AND D=5

 DROP TABLE T
```

#### 1 Pages / 245 rows

This plan has a seek on `A=1 AND B=2` with a residual predicate on `(C=@C1 OR C=@C2) AND D=5`

[image: Plan 1]

#### 2 leaf Pages / 246 rows

[image: Plan 2]

In the second plan the extra operators are responsible for removing any duplicates from `@C1,@C2` first before performing the seek(s).

The seek in the second plan is actually a range seek between `A=1 AND B=2 AND C > Expr1010` and `A=1 AND B=2 AND C < Expr1011` with a residual predicate on `D=5`. It still isn't an equality seek on all 4 columns. More information about the additional plan operators [can be found here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx).

Adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` does allow it to inspect the parameter values for duplicates at compile time and produces a plan with two equality seeks.

You could also achieve that with

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT ( C )
         FROM   (VALUES (@C1),
                        (@C2)) V(C))
SELECT CA.*
FROM   CTE
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   T
                    WHERE A=1 AND B=2 AND D=5  AND C = CTE.C) CA
```

[image: Plan 3]

But actually in this test case it would likely be counter productive as having two seeks into the single page index rather than one increases the logical IO.

Comment: Did some testing on this question last night before you added your first comment. I came as far as seeing the behavior but did not get what was causing it (@P3 = @P4) so +1 for that (already did). I think a `select .. union select ...` would also give you two seeks plus the additional step of removing duplicates from the result.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - But `SELECT * FROM T WHERE A=1 AND B=2 AND C=@C1 AND D=5 UNION SELECT * FROM T WHERE A=1 AND B=2 AND C=@C2 AND D=5` could incorrectly remove duplicates that should be returned. In my example data where I lazily populated all with the same value it would return 1 row not `256`

Comment: Ah, yes. And OP even specified that the key is non-unique. Lucke me I did not try to answer this one :).

Answer (score 4):

Totally agree with Martin's analysis. This query cannot produce a seek on all 4 columns due to the OR predicate, unless (maybe) with OPTION (RECOMPILE). I am guessing this being a needle-in-a-haystack query, you probably don't want the extra overhead.

How about this:

```
IF @P3=@P4
    SELECT * FROM T WHERE A=@P1 AND B=@P2 AND C=@P3 AND D=@P5.
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM T WHERE A=@P1 AND B=@P2 AND C=@P3 AND D=@P5.
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM T WHERE A=@P1 AND B=@P2 AND C=@P4 AND D=@P5.
```

I didn't test this but the else part should give 2 seeks on all 4 values and a cheap union through concatenation. In case when both seeks end up in the same page I don't think an extra logical page read would add much time. However, depending on your data, the two seeks may very well be on different pages.